# Unpacked a tar...badly - now locked out of my own files!

Tags: permissions, home-directory, delete

Not knowing well what I was doing, I opened a tar with sudo, and now it's linked to a user that doesn't exist and I can't remove it under any circumstances - perhaps because it's off the home directory.  Help please?

```
total 44
drwx------ 2 3047 3047  4096 Sep 25  2012 library
drwx------ 2 3047 3047  4096 Sep 25  2012 source
drwx------ 2 3047 3047  4096 Sep 25  2012 examples
-rw-rw-rw- 1 q    q    28828 May  6 07:02 image_processing.tar.gz
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'linked to a user'?

Comment: some random numeric user name has permissions to open or otherwise affect the directories and files : S

Comment: Can you please execute `ls -ltr` and include the output in your question?

Comment: output is now included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do `sudo chown $USER <path to file>` in terminal to change yourself to its owner.

then do `sudo chmod 755 <path to file>` to change it to usual permissions.

Comment: So far, so good!  Will do one more update - but I think you've just restored my day : )

Comment: `$USER` will automagically change it to your current user ;)

Comment: Yep - day == saved!  Thanks again!  I'll come up with somewhere better to store my files, and I'll make a note of the commands used, just in case : )